# Where are all the settings written when we disable or enable specific platform for flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I just disabled a few platforms (`android`, `ios`, `macos`) for my new flutter project.

I used the command `flutter config --no-disable-<platform>` and here is the output.

[image]

I want to know if there is any configuration file that flutter writes to store these settings globally.

It will help me to directly change the value for my next project directly by modifying the file.